# Why is this Idris function not total and what could be done to make it check total?

Tags: idris, totality

This Idris function does not successfully check for totality, however in my mind it seems that all cases are covered. This is my merge function in a merge sort.

Using Idris version 1.3.3

Error.

```
*d:/home/projects/testidris/test> :total merge2
Main.merge2 is possibly not total due to:
    Main.case block in case block in merge2 at d:\home\projects\testidris\test.idr:11:22-47 at d:\home\projects\testidris\test.idr:12:22-31, which is not total as there are missing cases
```

Idris.

```
module Main

record Mergeable where
    constructor MkMergeable
    left : List Nat
    right : List Nat

merge2 : Mergeable -> List Nat
merge2 (MkMergeable [] right) = right
merge2 (MkMergeable left []) = left
merge2 (input) = let MkMergeable (left) (right) = input;
                     (a1 :: a2) = left;
                     (b1 :: b2) = right in
                 if a1 < b1 then a1 :: merge2 (MkMergeable a2 right)
                 else b1 :: merge2 (MkMergeable left b2)
```

Comment: I think Idris 1 is dead. I would recommend Idris 2. Also I think using `Mergeable` is confusing Idris. Does it work with `merge2 : List Nat -> List Nat -> List Nat`?